# Is it possible to define the Serre mod $\mathscr{C}$ model category structure on $r$-reduced simplicial sets as Cisinski model structure?

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories

I think it is quite straightforward to show that a $\bmod\mathscr{C}$ model structure on $r$-reduced simplicial sets is a Bousfield localization of the transferred Kan-Quillen model structure.

However, trying to internalize concepts from $\S$ 2.4 of Cisinski's [book](https://cisinski.app.uni-regensburg.de/CatLR.pdf), I came up with a question that I couldn't resolve. First of all, it seems that we can identify the category $\mathcal{sSet}_r$ of $r$-reduced simplicial sets with the presheaf category on the category $\mathbf{\Delta}_{\ge r}$ of finite ordinals of cardinality at least $r.$ Then it seems that we can take the usual cylinder on $\mathcal{sSet}$ to induce a cylinder on $\mathcal{sSet}_r.$ It looks like this choice reproduces the transferred Kan-Quillen model structure.

But what happens if we want to localize in $\bmod \mathscr{C}$-equivalences? Is it possible to find some other cylinder $J:\mathcal{sSet}_r\to \mathcal{sSet}_r$ such that it gives the localized model structure? It seems that Theorem 3.54 from [the nlab article](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Cisinski+model+structure#ALocalizer) gives a positive answer. However, it looks like the cylinder chosen there is quite large and unmanageable (the Lawvere cylinder). Is it possible to produce some smaller cylinder giving the same model structure?

Is there a more general discussion around the relation between Bousfield localization of topoi (and in particular presheaf topoi) and Cisinski model structures? In particular, is there an economical way to construct a cylinder that gives the localized model structure?

This is a [cross-post from MSE.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4582400/is-it-possible-to-define-the-serre-mod-mathscrc-model-category-structure-on)

Comment: This is not an answer, but I want to point out a paper (of mine, with Batanin) that considers the relationship between Bousfield localization and Cisinski model structures, constructing localizations in a bit more generality in Section 9. But, it doesn't give me any insight into your question about cylinders: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.05432.pdf